# How do I disable the c# message box beep?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Whenever trigger a messagebox used in my C# program I get a very annoying beep from my computer.  How do I disable this beep using C# code.

The code I am using is very simple.

```
MessageBox.show("text");
```

Comment: I believe there is no way to control this for individual message box; it's a windows setting. Does this make this question belong on superuser.com?

Comment: I was asking if there is any c# code I could write to make the beep go away just for my program.  I was not asking for a setting specific to just my system.  I will clarify my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the searching I've done it looks like the beep is hardwired into the Win32 message box function:

- [Bytes](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/269836-turn-off-beep-when-messagebox-show)
- [VB Forums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=531843)

So you need to either write your own method or stop the beep in the hardware. The former will work for everyone, the latter just for you.

Comment: Here's another article for those who feel the urge to create their own MessageBox replacement: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19711/Creating-A-Custom-Message-Box-Part

Answer (score 9):

Despite this question being old I had the same problem but was able to fix it in a very simple way.

```
MessageBox.Show("Your text here", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
```

By setting the `MessageBoxIcon` to `None` the system produces no sound. However, there will be no icon on the box. Something like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/4b004f0a15a9a75b27b08f574af4cef0.png).

Comment: It's a strange behavior. It works. The message is now horrible...

Answer (score 6):

This is going to sound weird until you have tried it.  Open your command prompt, type:

```
net stop beep
```

I did a quick google and found 4 other ways:

1. local machine: sc stop beep && sc config beep start= disabled
2. remote machine: sc \remoteMachine stop beep && sc \remoteMachine config beep start= disabled
3. requires reboot: Device Manager -> View -> Show Hidden Devices -> Non Plug and Play -> Beep -> Disable
4. use TweakUI: General > Settings -> Uncheck the Beep on Errors

[(from here)](http://blog.netnerds.net/2007/05/5-ways-to-stop-windows-vista-xp-2003-from-beeping/)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I solved that little problem.

Add this simple class to your project. It's part of my personal library now but you can add the class directly in your project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyCSharpLibrary
{
    public class Volume
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr h, out uint dwVolume);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr h, uint dwVolume);

        private static uint _savedVolumeLevel;
        private static Boolean VolumeLevelSaved = false;

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void On()
        {
            if (VolumeLevelSaved)
            {
                waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, _savedVolumeLevel);
            }
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void Off()
        {
            waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out _savedVolumeLevel);
            VolumeLevelSaved = true;

            waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now call     Volume.Off() before calling MessageBox and Volume.On() after

```
Volume.Off();
MessageBox.Show("\n Information \n", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
Volume.On();
```

I prefer that approach because I don't have to make modifications to Windows and I can select any icons I want for my MessageBoxes.

Thank you, bye

Comment: using your approach will cause the whole window volume to mute, what if the user  is listening to music? he'll have a mute for a second

Answer (score 5):

Try using the VisualBasic MsgBox class instead of the MessageBox.   I cannot explain why, but on my computer, the VisualBasic one doesn't beep.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28VS.85%29.aspx

So instead of:

```
MessageBox.Show("text")
```

do:

```
MsgBox("text")
```

You'll have to import the MsgBox function from Microsoft.VisualBasic, instead of importing MessageBox from System.Windows.Forms.   But that shouldn't be a problem; it's part of the .NET api.

EDIT:  Ah ok, now I can explain it.  The lack of sound is because the VB version of the MessageBox is undecorated (i.e. it's not informational, a question, etc.) by default.  I assume there's no real need to use the VB MsgBox class after all--probably if you make the regular old MessageBox undecorated, it won't make any sound either. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should leave it to the end user to decide what sounds he wants.
He can configure/disable sounds for system events such as a messagebox in Control Panel / Sounds and Audio Devices / Sounds / Program Events.

Stopping the beep service required administrative privileges, and isn't something you'd normally do just for one application.

If you do go for a custom dialog to replace the MessageBox, please remember to implement CTL-C (copy messagebox contents to clipboard).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much you're leveraging the MessageBox (icons, etc) you can always make a custom dialog. Especially if it's a simple message you want to display, this would not be difficult or time consuming.