# pling sound .net application

Tags: .net, winforms

i have a .net winforms application that i want to be "soundless".

occasionally when a user opens a dialog or press enter a "pling" sound appears. how can i disable this on a global scale for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this previous article:

[How do I disable the c# message box beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738980/how-do-i-disable-the-c-message-box-beep)