# Stop "Beep" when messageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a windows form that shows messageBox as a warning some data has been missed,

Is there a way i can disable the "beep" from the pc whenever a messageBox is shown.

I have seen some people doing it in the PC settings but i would really like it to be setable depending what messageBox is showm, asin "beep" for some messageBox and not for others.

Cheers
Ryan

Comment: Sounds bad for you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738980/how-do-i-disable-the-c-sharp-message-box-beep

Answer (score 3):

As the two comments indicated it is not possible. You could write your own messagebox class if it is that important (isn't THAT hard).